# I need to return the value amount from two seperate sheets with the criteria for match of date and text

Tags: excel-formula, match, return-value, z-index

[image: Example screenshot]

I tried Sumifs and Index and Match.  I have even reviewed several posts on this site.  I am not getting the results i need.  any help appreciated.  In my example below If B2 & A4 in Sheet 1 match then return value so that i can see the amount that matches the text and date.  I want this to be a daily file that we can add to and get the data instantly.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some sample data (best using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)) and your expected output - then it is much easier to help you. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).